# submit me the requirements or submit the requirements

Tags: grammar

Please advise which sentence is correct.

Do not **submit me** the requirements that are stated in the attachment.

Do not **submit** the requirements that are stated in the attachment **to me**.

Thank you

Comment: You need the "to" no matter where you put the "me".

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any possibility of ambiguity, you might break the sentence into clauses dedicated to (1) acknowledging the existence of requirements in the attachment, and (2) insisting that the reader or recipient of your instructions not send those requirements to you. Here is one way to do it:

> The attachment identifies certain requirements that you must meet, but you should not submit any information related to those requirements to me.

Answer (score 0):

Better to not mention "me" at all.  If the idea is that they should fill out and return a form, but not the instructions that were sent along with it: Say "Please [submit/return] the completed [form/application], but do not return [these/the attached] [Requirements/Instructions]."